# TmdbLib Help Discovering Movies between two different dates

Tags: vb.net, themoviedb-api

OK, so I'm using VS2015 and using Visual Basic with 4.6 framework. My issue is with TMDB, the movie database (http://themoviedb.org) and the library I'm using I've added it using nuGET.

My code is following in my module:

Well, first my form load is calling the sub like this:

```
DiscoverMoviesByCustomDates ("2014-09-15", "2014-10-22")
```

I also tried reversing the dates to month-day-year for both dates as pass it through the sub. Also tried replacing the dates in quotes with `new DateTime (year, month, day)` for both dates and still same response of movie from 2006.

I

```
Public Module modTMDB

    Public Results As New SearchContainer (Of SearchMovie) 
    Public Client As New TMDBClient ("my apikey")

    Public Sub DiscoverMoviesByCustomDates (ByVal dateStart As Date, ByVal dateEnd As Date)

        Dim Discovery As DiscoverMovies

        Discovery = Client.DiscoverMoviesAsync().WherePrimaryReleaseDateIsAfter (dateStart).WherePrimaryReleaseDateIsBefore (dateEnd)
        Results = Discovery.Query(1).Results ' the 1 is the page number 
        Msgbox (Results.Results(0).Title & vbcrLF & Results.Results(0).ReleaseDate)   ' zero is index of array of results 
    End Sub
End Module
```

Any help would be appreciated. You can locate the TMDBLib via NuGET. I also even tried using `Discovery.OrderBy (Discovery.ReleaseDateDesc).Query().Results` as well and continue to get movies from 2006, or 2019. When I use tmdb website and enter the url manually the first movie by the dates I'm attempting, should be John Wick at index 0.

Has anyone else used or any knowledge of this library that could guide me in what I'm doing wrong? It's supposed to display moves from 10-22-2014 to 09-15-2014 that was playing in theaters. As I said, the wrapper doesn't display the right one but manually using the link returns correct results.

Comment: Use [this](https://github.com/LordMike/TMDbLib/issues).

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot try and reproduce your situation because it needs an API key, so perhaps writing an issue on github might be a good idea. Aside from that, does your code not need an `await` somewhere, like in [this](https://github.com/LordMike/TMDbLib/issues/224) snippet?